# Find the area of the region $\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq x^2+3, 0\leq y \leq 2x+3, 0\leq x\leq 3\}$

Tags: calculus

Okay, so my previous question was accused that I did not try the sum myself (although I had, just hadn't mentioned it here). Anyway, so here I have separated out the equations that are required to find the area (makes it easy for me to find the region), which came as follows: 
$$x\geq 0, \quad y\geq 0, \quad x\leq 3, \quad y\leq 2x+3, \quad y\leq x^2+3.$$

Now, I was able to draw a rough sketch of the thing, and it came out something like a standing trapezium, with one of the non-parallel side to be an arc (facing out). Now, how am I supposed to construct the equations to find the area? Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere in what I've done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now you find the point $x$ such that the two curves intersect, that is solve $x^2+3=2x+3$ for $x$. Call this point $z$ then next you integrate one curve from zero $z$ and then you integrate the other curve from $z$ to $3$. Look at your picture to figure out which curve you need to integrate.

Comment: the points are (0,3) and (2,7). Still stuck at which curve is to be integrated.

Comment: label the curves in your picture and their intersection points, the integral is the area under a curve.